# strange behavior of keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

The situation is the following, when the cube needs to rotate along the X axis (from -40deg to 40deg), it jumps for some reason, at the end of the animation I do the opposite (from 40deg to -40deg) and the cube rotates normally. 
Tell me please, what could be the reason! The code is shown below ....

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 500px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  perspective: 10000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
}

.box11 {
  animation: rot11 12s linear infinite;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  color: white;
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(1em);
  background: linear-gradient(153deg, #e66465, #9198e5);
  animation: topUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

.right {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
  animation: rightUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
  background: linear-gradient(127deg, #c45a5b, #6f76b2);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
  animation: bottomUCol 24s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rot11 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg) translate3d(0, -507px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(44deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box box11'>
    <div class='left side '></div>
    <div class='right side'></div>
    <div class='top side'></div>
    <div class='bottom side'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

l me please, what could be the reason! The code is shown below ....

Comment: Looks ok to me, no jump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN translateX() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateX) writes this about translateX()

> The rotateX() CSS function defines a transformation that rotates an
>   element around the abscissa (horizontal axis) without deforming it.
>   Its result is a  data type.
>
> The axis of rotation passes through an origin, defined by the
>   transform-origin CSS property.

**What is 'the origin'?**

[MDN transform-origin documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) writes this about the transform-origin:

> The transformation origin is the point around which a transformation
>   is applied. For example, the transformation origin of the rotate()
>   function is the center of rotation. (This property is applied by first
>   translating the element by the negated value of the property, then
>   applying the element's transform, then translating by the property
>   value.)

**Let's sum this up.**

- The browsers checks for an origin that corresponds to the element we are treating.
- The browser draws a fictional horizontal line (horizontal axis) through this point.
- When you apply `rotateX()` the element it rotates around this axis.

**How does `translate3d()` affect my rotation.**

`translate3d()` moves the element along its x, y and z-axis in regard to its origin. If you move an element along its y-axis (you create a distance between the x-axis and the element), the rotation will rotate the element at the created distance from the x-axis. To see this in action see the code example.

**Additional reading**

If you are really interested in how this works behind the scenes, you might want to read up on matrices. Matrices are also used behind the scenes for other operations (e.g. all kinds of filter effects in SVG). You can read up on [MDN documentation: Matrix math for the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Matrix_math_for_the_web).

**Since you asked for the reason I didn't use your code but made this example to illustrate what happens:**

Here is a link to [my codePen of the same code](https://codepen.io/RobMo/pen/JLWWwg) (might be easier to watch).

```js
// don't pay attention to the javascript, it doesn't do anything aside from changing the text.
function setDescription (newText, timeout){ 
 setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('description').innerText = newText;
  }, timeout);
}

setDescription ('Rotating around X-axis', 0);
setDescription ('Rotating around Y-axis', 7000);
setDescription ('Move along the Y-axis', 14000);
setDescription ('Rotating around X-axis', 16000);
setDescription ('Returning to starting position', 22000);
setDescription ('Reload to replay', 24000);
```

```css
#container{
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
#description{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#x-axis{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  width: 400px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
#y-axis{
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50px - 1px);
  top: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

#object{
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: 
    rotateAroundX 3s linear 0s 2, /*0 - 6s*/
    rotateAroundY 3s linear 7s 2, /*7 - 13s*/
    moveAlongY 2s linear 14s, /*14 - 16s*/
    rotateAroundXAndTranslateY 3s linear 16s 2, /* 16 - 22s*/
    moveBackAlongY 2s linear 22s; /* 22 - 24s*/
}

@keyframes rotateAroundX{
  0%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateAroundY{
  0%{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateAroundXAndTranslateY{
  0%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotateX(360deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes moveAlongY{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes moveBackAlongY{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<h3 id="description"></h3>
  <div id="x-axis"></div>
  <div id="y-axis"></div>
  <div id="object"></div>
</div>
```